# Twitter API get tweets - returns CORS origin blocked

Tags: angularjs, twitter, oauth-2.0, cors, twitter-oauth

I am trying to get tweets from a hashtag. I get following erros Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?f=tweets&q=%23shruthirajoli&src=typd?get=%5Bobject+Object%5D. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)

Below is my code:
app.js

```
var app = angular.module('Twitter', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('TwitterCtrl', function($scope,$http,$resource){
// Create Base64 Object
    var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
    encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},
    decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}

    var consumerKey = encodeURIComponent('');
    var consumerSecret = encodeURIComponent('');
    var credentials = Base64.encode(consumerKey + ':' + consumerSecret);
    // Twitters OAuth service endpoint
    var twitterOauthEndpoint = $http.post('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', "grant_type=client_credentials"
    , {headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'}});
    twitterOauthEndpoint.success(function (response) {
                // a successful response will return
                // the "bearer" token which is registered
                // to the $httpProvider
                console.log(twitterOauthEndpoint );
    app.$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + response.access_token})
    .error(function (response) {
                  // error handling to some meaningful extent
                });
    $scope.twitter = $resource('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?f=tweets&q=%23shruthirajoli&src=typd',
       // {action: 'search.json', q:'angularjs', callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'},
        {get:{method:'JSONP'}});

    $scope.twitterResult = $scope.twitter.get();
});


app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    app.$httpProvider = $httpProvider
});

html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Twitter">
<head>
    <script  src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-resource-1.0.0rc4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="TwitterCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="tweet in twitterResult.results">
            <td>{{tweet.text}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am running this on localhost:8000, I followed twisters instructions to troubleshoot this. Can someone let me know, if I am making any mistake. thanks.

Comment: You'll need to look at the headers in the PRE-FLIGHT request and response.  I suspect that they are missing the access-control-allow-headers header.  That particular header is needed when you set and/or read non-standard header values.  It's the server's way of telling the browser to let the cross domain page see a custom header.

Comment: Beware of localhost testing with CORS:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin

Comment: If/when you resolve the localhost issue, post the headers of the request and response (available in the developer tools network tab if using Chrome).  Then we can debug further.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twitter API authorization fails CORS preflight in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879943/twitter-api-authorization-fails-cors-preflight-in-browser)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting this error is because your making the request through the browser. Browsers don't allow cross domain requests because like @allenru mentioned in the comments below: Servers need to response according to the CORS spec so the browser can proceed with the request.

You can learn more about it here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

The proper way to fetch tweets would be making a call to the server and have the server fetch tweets for you.

This also seems like a buggy call. 
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?f=tweets&q=%23shruthirajoli&src=typd?get=%5Bobject+Object%5D.
Its not normal to have `[object + object]` in requests. It seems like an object that was not stringified.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Browser enforce the CORS protocol, and will allow cross domain requests.

Comment: @allenru If the user disables their browser security the browser will make CORS requests just fine, but I dont think he was asking how to override browser security.

Comment: The browser enforces the CORS spec that you linked to.  In this case, he's setting a custom header (Authorization) which will trigger a pre-flight request (an HTTP OPTIONS request).  If the server does not respond according to the CORS spec, the browser will not proceed with the primary request.  This is the default behavior of the browser.  No security overrides are necessary.

Comment: @allenru I completely agree with you. Thank you for providing an explanation for why the browser ill not make the request. I gave you a credit in the answer.

Comment: Crud.  It looks like Twitter doesn't support CORS requests, acording to this ticket and a number of posts:  https://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=2273

@mbejda thanks for the update.  If you'll note that this is a problem with Twitter's servers (lack of CORS support on their part) then I think we've solved (proved its not possible) shruthi 's question.

Comment: thank you both of you for your response, I was troubleshooting and came across CORS plugin in chrome, I tried enabling it and running the app, it throws following erros Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (OK)
localhost/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400