# Twitter API Fetch Request returning CORS error

Tags: reactjs, twitter, fetch

So I have been trying to us the Twitter AP https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/quick-start in a React application that I have been working on. I am using the `fetch` API to simply hit the endpoint mentioned in the quick start tutorial.

Everytime I try to hit the endpoint in the browser I get the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by?user.fields=&usernames=trengriffin,awealthofcs,ReformedBroker,michaelbatnick,Wu_Tang_Finance&tweet.fields=author_id,created_at' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

However, when I hit this URL with the same params with postman I get the data back correctly. I assume it has to be how I am using the `fetch` API but I am not seeing any examples online to fix this issue.

Here is the code:

```js
const endpointUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by?user.fields=&usernames=trengriffin,awealthofcs,ReformedBroker,michaelbatnick,Wu_Tang_Finance&tweet.fields=author_id,created_at';
const TwitterContainer: React.FC<ContainerProps> = () => {
   useEffect( () => {
      fetch(endpointUrl, {
         mode: 'cors',
         credentials: 'include',
         headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
         },

      }).then(res => res.json())
          .then(console.log)
          .catch(console.error);
```

Im not sure why I am still getting an error. According to the `fetch` documents, you have to use `credentials: include` for HTTPS requests, but I am still getting a CORS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter API does not support CORS. For more information see this question: [Twitter API authorization fails CORS preflight in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879943/twitter-api-authorization-fails-cors-preflight-in-browser)

Comment: That is absurd. Thanks for your help.