# React - Trying to get Tweets from Twitter API - Cors and network error

Tags: reactjs, twitter, axios

I'm trying to fetch tweets from the Twitter API but I'm receiving network error and blocked by CORS error. I'm not sure what should I write differently or if I'm even setting up the header correctly to receive the response.

This is the code I have so far:

```
const Tweets = () => {
    const [tweets, setTweets] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = process.env.REACT_APP_TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN;
        async function fetchTweets() {
            const res = await axios.get('https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=%23ux', {
                headers: {
                     'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`
                }
            });

            if(res) {
                setTweets(res.data);
            }
    
            console.log(res.data);
            return res;
        }
        
        fetchTweets();
        
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default Tweets;
```

Comment: Try 'Bearer' instead of 'bearer' in your authorization header.

Comment: @Junior Receiving the same error with 'Bearer' unfortunately

Comment: From what I'm reading here, the API does not support requests from the JS API calls
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35898961/8188471